# How can I display iOS AppStore top 100 on website similarly to 148apps?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, itunes

How would I be able to display a list of iOS AppSore rankings, in real time, on my Wordpress blog?

The categories I'd like to display are:

- Top 75 Paid Apps
- Top 75 Free Apps
- Popular App Sales

Similar to 148Apps or AppAdvice.

Any answers/solutions would be great.

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 2):

Apple provides [various RSS feeds](http://itunes.apple.com/rss) to access different rankings. You can then simply parse them in PHP or any other language. You can use a cronjob or any other background worker to update the rankings periodically.

Comment: I've got the RSS feed part — how exactly would I parse it? Haven't done much in terms of PHP in my past.